# React does not rerender

Tags: reactjs

I have an issue with react rerendering. Every time i trigger one of the commissionService axios functions, this simply does nothing and I have to manually refresh the page in order to see the changes.

Here you find the involved functions

```
import { getCommissions, updateCommission, deleteCommission, addCommission } from '../services/commissionService';

useEffect(() => {
        getCommissions()
            .then((response) => setCommissions(response?.data))
            .then(() => {
                const integerComID = commissions?.map((customer: any) => ({
                    ...customer,
                    client_id: parseInt(customer.client_id),
                }));
                setInitialRecords(sortBy(integerComID, 'client_id'));
            })
            .then(() => setCommissionsNotEmpty(true));

        dispatch(setPageTitle('Commissions'));
        dispatch(setSearchInputs(searchInputsStatus));
    }, [commissionsNotEmpty]);
```

getCommissions() MUST be recalled and MUST cause a rerendering in the whole component every time an axios function from commissionService is triggered.

I tried to solve this issue by putting the commissionService axios functions into the dependency array of getCommissions().

Nothing.

Still have to manually refresh.

What can I do?

Comment: Where does commissions (that you are mapping) come from?
Where does setInitialRecords function come from? 
Perhaps these are dependencies??

Comment: this question needs an axios tag otherwise you are asking for the needle in the haystack

Comment: @ScottGnile using commissions as dependency causes an infinite loop, same for initialRecords